# ¿Cómo usar el acces token de Spotify?

Tags: java, api

Estoy intentando usar la API de Spotify para añadir canciones a una playlist pero no se como tengo que usar el  accestoken. En otras APIs se incluye en la URI pero aquí mirando la [documentación](https://beta.developer.spotify.com/console/playlists/) veo que no.

En Facebook por ejemplo sería así:

```
package es.us.eii.server.resources;

import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;
import org.restlet.resource.ResourceException;

import es.us.eii.shared.domain.facebook.FacebookFriends;

public class FacebookFriendsResource {

private String uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends";
private String access_token = null;


public FacebookFriendsResource(String access_token) {
    this.access_token = access_token;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return FacebookFriends
 */
public FacebookFriends getFriends() {

    ClientResource cr = null;
    FacebookFriends list = null;

    try {
        cr = new ClientResource(uri + "?access_token=" + access_token);
        list = cr.get(FacebookFriends.class);

    } catch (ResourceException re) {
        System.err.println("Error when retrieving friends: " + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
        System.err.println(uri + "?access_token" + access_token);
    }

    return list;

    }
}
```

Spotify:

```
package aiss.model.resources;

import java.util.logging.Logger;


import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;
import org.restlet.resource.ResourceException;

import com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.protobuf.Api;

import aiss.model.spotify.Playlists;


import aiss.model.spotify.Tracks;


public class SpotifyResource {
private static final Logger log=Logger.getLogger(SpotifyResource.class.getName());

private String uriTrack = " https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/";
private String uriPlaylist = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/";



// METODO PARA OBTENER UN TRACK
public Tracks getTracks(String trackId) {
    ClientResource cr = null;
    Tracks track = null;
    try {
        cr = new ClientResource(uriTrack + trackId);
        track = cr.get(Tracks.class);

    } catch (ResourceException re) {
        System.out.println("Error  al recuperar  la busqueda:" + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
        throw re;
    }

    return track;
}

//METODO PARA OBTENER LA LISTA DE PLAYLIST DE UN USUARIO
public Playlists getPlaylist(String userId) {
    ClientResource cr = null;
    Playlists playlist = null;
    try {
        cr = new ClientResource(uriPlaylist + userId + "/playlists");
        playlist = cr.get(Playlists.class);

    } catch (ResourceException re) {
        System.err.println("Error when adding the playlist: " + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
    }

    return playlist;
}


// METODO PARA CREAR UNA PLAYLIST PARA UN USUARIO
public Playlists addPlaylist( Playlists playlist, String userId) {
    ClientResource cr = null;
    Playlists newPlaylist = null;
    try {
        cr = new ClientResource(uriPlaylist + userId + "/playlists");
        cr.setEntityBuffering(true);
    newPlaylist=cr.post(playlist,Playlists.class);

    } catch (ResourceException re) {
        System.out.println("Error  al recuperar  la busqueda:" + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
    throw re;
    }

    return newPlaylist;
}

// METODO PARA ELIMINAR UNA PLAYLIST
public boolean removePlaylist(String playlistId,String userId) {
    ClientResource cr = null;
    boolean success = true;
    try {
        cr = new ClientResource(uriPlaylist + userId+"/playlists/"+playlistId+"/tracks");
        cr.setEntityBuffering(true);
        cr.delete();

    } catch (ResourceException re) {
        System.out.println("Error  al recuperar  la busqueda:" + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}

// METODOS PARA METER UN TRACK EN UNA PLAYLIST
public boolean addTrackToPlaylist(String playlistId, String userId) {
    ClientResource cr = null;
    boolean success = true;
    try {
        cr = new ClientResource(uriPlaylist + userId+ "/playlists/"+playlistId+"/tracks");
        cr.setEntityBuffering(true);
        cr.post(" ");
    } catch (ResourceException re) {
        System.out.println("Error  al recuperar  la busqueda:" + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
        success = false;
        ;
    }

    return success;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spotify requiere que el token vaya como un *header* en cada request. Tienes que añadirlo con este formato (Típico de un token JWT):

```
"Authorization": "Bearer <token aquí>"
```